# AWS data pipeline get data from hive to s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, jdbc, hive, amazon-data-pipeline

I have created a aws data pipeline to get the data from hive to s3.
I have created a emr cluster and set up the hive and using jdbc connection trying to connect hive from the pipeline.

Below is the error I am getting
org/apache/hive/jdbc/HiveDriver : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/hive/jdbc/HiveDriver : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:808) at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:443) at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:65) at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:349) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:348) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:430) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363) at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278) at amazonaws.datapipeline.database.JdbcDriverInitializer.getDriver(JdbcDriverInitializer.java:75) at amazonaws.datapipeline.database.ConnectionFactory.getJdbcDatabaseConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:222) at amazonaws.datapipeline.database.ConnectionFactory.getConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:75) at amazonaws.datapipeline.database.ConnectionFactory.getConnectionWithCredentials(ConnectionFactory.java:301) at amazonaws.datapipeline.connector.SqlDataNode.createConnection(SqlDataNode.java:100) at amazonaws.datapipeline.connector.SqlDataNode.getConnection(SqlDataNode.java:94) at amazonaws.datapipeline.connector.SqlDataNode.prepareStatement(SqlDataNode.java:162) at amazonaws.datapipeline.connector.SqlInputConnector.open(SqlInputConnector.java:48) at amazonaws.datapipeline.connector.SqlInputConnector.(SqlInputConnector.java:25) at amazonaws.datapipeline.connector.SqlDataNode.getInputConnector(SqlDataNode.java:79) at amazonaws.datapipeline.activity.copy.SingleThreadedCopyActivity.processAll(SingleThreadedCopyActivity.java:47) at amazonaws.datapipeline.activity.copy.SingleThreadedCopyActivity.runActivity(SingleThreadedCopyActivity.java:35) at amazonaws.datapipeline.activity.CopyActivity.runActivity(CopyActivity.java:22) at amazonaws.datapipeline.objects.AbstractActivity.run(AbstractActivity.java:16) at amazonaws.datapipeline.taskrunner.TaskPoller.executeRemoteRunner(TaskPoller.java:136) at amazonaws.datapipeline.taskrunner.TaskPoller.executeTask(TaskPoller.java:105) at amazonaws.datapipeline.taskrunner.TaskPoller$1.run(TaskPoller.java:81) at private.com.amazonaws.services.datapipeline.poller.PollWorker.executeWork(PollWorker.java:76) at private.com.amazonaws.services.datapipeline.poller.PollWorker.run(PollWorker.java:53) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Can someone help me with this?

I am using the Hive 2.3.7,
this is the driver I am using hive-jdbc-uber-2.6.5.0-292.jar

Comment: The error means the driver is compiled for Java 8 (class version 52.0), but your application is running on Java 7 or earlier.

Comment: Using aws data pipeline, used the driver HiveJDBC4.jar and given the class name as 
com.amazon.hive.jdbc4.HS1Driver and trying to connect the hive tables.

The connection is success, but not able to retrieve the data.